# Javascript function variables issue

Tags: jquery

What is the problem with my script? When I execute it, the alert (line 2) gives me "100,200,300undefinedundefined", so is seems like 100,200,300 is interpreted as h1 when I would like it to be h1, h2 and h3 (with the commas).

```
function myanimation(h1,h2,h3) {

        alert(h1 + h2 + h3);
        $("#h1").animate({"left": h1});
        $("#h2").animate({"left": h2});
    }

    var moves = new Array()
    moves[1] = [100,200,300];
    moves[2] = [300,200,100];
    moves[3] = [-500,-300,0];

    var i = 1;

    function animatenow(){
        myanimation(moves[i]);
        i++;
    }

$('#launch').click(function() {
        setInterval(animatenow, 5000);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adam, you are passing in an array object into H1, not separate variables

You probably want to change

```
myanimation(moves[i]);
```

to:

```
myanimation(moves[i][0],moves[i][1],moves[i][2]);
```

Comment: Another question: when I use i++ in my function, it doesn't work; it always sends moves[1] so how can I make the i++ scope be global instead of local?

Comment: @AdamStrudwick it's not doing that for me. Could there be some other code that might be resetting i?

Answer (score 6):

You are passing an array into `myanimation`, which corresponds to your `h1` parameter.  You aren't passing `h2` or `h3`, so those are undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing an array to `myanimation` where it expects three parameters.

`myanimation(moves[i]);` where `moves[1] = [100,200,300]`

So `h1` in your `myanimation` would be `[100,200,300]`

Change it to expect an array:

```
function myanimation(moves) {
    $("#h1").animate({"left": moves[1]}); // moves[1] is 100
    $("#h2").animate({"left": moves[2]}); // 200
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your codes, should the following codes like this?

```
function animatenow(){
    myanimation(moves[i][0], moves[i][1], moves[i][2]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Another question: when I use i++ in my function, it doesn't work; it always sends moves[1] so how can I make the i++ scope be global instead of local?